# Input sound of a specific application and microphone from USB headset into Discord using PulseAudio

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

I would like to know how to use PulseAudio to set my input into Discord as both a specific application as well as my USB headset's mic. I can't simply input all internal sound because then I send back Discord's audio, resulting in listeners hearing their own voices, so I am seeking a way to send only a specific application. It's simple enough to send only the application, but I can't figure out a way to also send the microphone audio as well. I'm running Ubuntu MATE 16.04.

Comment: You'll need a null sink ("virtual" sink) as output sink for the specific application, the `.monitor` source of this sink as input to Discord, and a `module-loopback` to connect the source of your headset's mic to the null sink. There should be similar questions with details.

Comment: you may need to load additional Pulseaudio module module-combine-sink as well as the other modules mentioned. routing this audio may sound simple but is not easy to get the 'mix-minus' audio to send to discord listeners without their voices being echoed back. for better mixing and routing control could use JACK audio server in Linux or small analog mixing desk